# Visual Studio 2013 : Access violation when attempt to change value of variable obtained from LockResource()

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I am moving my project from Visual studio 2010 to Visual studio 2013. I found that part of code which were working fine on Visual studio 2010 is not working when build with 2013. Below is part of code snippet in question.

```
int DoDialog(UINT id, HWND hwndParent, DLGPROC lpDialogFunc, LPARAM lParamInit)
{
    HGLOBAL         hgl = NULL;
    LPDLGTEMPLATE lpTemplate = NULL;
    HRSRC hRC = FindResourceEx(hInst, RT_DIALOG, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id),LANGIDFROMLCID(GetCurrentLocale()));
    hgl = LoadResource(hInst, hRC);
    lpTemplate = (LPDLGTEMPLATE)LockResource(hgl);
    if (hRC && hgl && lpTemplate)
    {
        lpTemplate->dwExtendedStyle |= WS_EX_TOPMOST; // ---> This part of code run without
                                                      // problem in visual studio version 2010 
                                                      // (and older). 

        result = DialogBoxIndirectParam(hInst, lpTemplate, hwndParent, lpDialogFunc, lParamInit);
    }

    return result;
}
```

when program try to modify value of **lpTemplate->dwExtendedStyle**, it gives access violation in runtime. This code was working on Visual studio 2010. 
What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are read-only; if you want to modify one in memory, make a copy of it first.

```
int DoDialog(UINT id, HWND hwndParent, DLGPROC lpDialogFunc, LPARAM lParamInit)
{
    HGLOBAL         hgl = NULL;
    LPDLGTEMPLATE lpTemplate = NULL, pTemplateCopy = NULL;
    DWORD dwSize;
    HRSRC hRC = FindResourceEx(hInst, RT_DIALOG, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id),LANGIDFROMLCID(GetCurrentLocale()));
    hgl = LoadResource(hInst, hRC);
    lpTemplate = (LPDLGTEMPLATE)LockResource(hgl);

    // make a writeable copy of the resource
    dwSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hRC);
    if (pTemplateCopy = malloc(dwSize))
    {
        memcpy(pTemplateCopy, lpTemplate, dwSize);

        // now do something with the pTemplateCopy
        // remember to call free(pTemplateCopy) when done
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jonathan. It work :) still wonder why it worked before in version prior to VS-2013.

Comment: @someone_smiley: I don't think the compiler would make any difference, more likely is it worked on an older version of Windows (e.g. XP).

Comment: I tested both on Window 7 and this problem happen only when build from VS 2013. Thanks anyway :)